# Links open when scrolling on touch devices/mobile

Tags: links, mobile

On all touch devices both Android and iPhone and iPad, when scrolling with finger over a link the site opens the link instead of ignoring the press and just scrolling as touch devices normally do when scrolling.

I'm using WordPress 4.2.15 and building my own child theme off of twentythirteen.

Link: joshuachronstedt.dk

Plugins:
Advanced Custom Fields,
Advanced Custom Fields Multiligual,
Advanced iFrame,
All in one Favicon,
Disable Emails,
Duplicate Theme,
Insert Headers and Footers,
Instagram Feed,
jQuery Smooth Scroll (I have tried disabling this),
No Image Links,
Page Animations And Transitions,
Simple Custom Post Order,
SVG Support,
UpdraftPlus,
Video Thumbnails,
What The File,
WP-PageNavi,
WP Load More Posts,
WPML Multiligual CMS,
WPML String Translation,
WPML Translation Management.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could confirm on your shared site that some javascript code is causing this issue.

This code may be generated by plugins used on your site so please try temporary deactivating all plugins and see whether everything works fine and then enable the plugins one by one to see which plugin is generating it if any.

Also this can be generated by child theme used on your site so to confirm it just temporary use the twentythirteen theme instead of child theme on your site. If everything works fine then it's your child theme generating that code.

Comment: Thank you alot Vinod, I will try this and report back if it solves it.

Comment: I can report that it was it was the plugin "Page Animations And Transitions" that created the problem. Thank's alot Vinod you'r a champ!  The plugin also gave mobile users a blank page when going back to the front page from an article page.